# On click button show div after time period finish

Tags: javascript

I am wordpress user and I have a website. Its' bounce rate is high so I want a loader that will show a div onclick button after specific time period finish.

**Note:** when the time period will start it must show a loader in circle to user but the time period should be completed in background. User should not see seconds stuff like that only see a loader.

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      document.getElementById('content').style.display='block';
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 110%;
  float:center;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
#content{
    display:none;
}
#button{padding:1em;
margin:auto;}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
<br> 
<button onclick="move()">Download Movie</button>
<div id="conten"><br>

<p>hello loader is successful</p>

 
</div>

<script src="build/app.js?v=4" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-114581422-1"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow is a site for questions and answers. A list of requirements is not considered a question, and is not taken kindly by the community here. Please write your program, and if you have difficulty implementing any point, feel free to ask about that difficulty, showing your code, what you expected, and what went wrong.

Comment: after loader finish do you want to show `conten` div?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `function frame()`, you are setting the DOM element with ID **content** to be visible `document.getElementById('content').style.display='block';` and also in the CSS as `#content`.

But in the `HTML`, you have defined the ID of the `div` tag to be **conten** instead of **content**... (you missed the ending **t** in the html).

Edit: You have mentioned that you need a circular loader animation instead of the progress bar. Just replace the progress bar with a loader. You could create a simple circular loader using just `html` and `CSS`. When the progress is not yet 100%, display the loading animation. On completion, just hide it.

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 100);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      width++;
      document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 110%;
  float: center;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#content {
  display: none;
}

#button {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: auto;
}

.loader {
  border: 8px solid #000000; /* black */
  border-top: 8px solid #ffffff; /* white */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader" id="loader">
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Download Movie</button>
<div id="content"><br>

  <p>hello loader is successful</p>

</div>

<script src="build/app.js?v=4" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-114581422-1"></script>
```

Comment: this code is working well here but its not working in wordpress I put css in css file and js code in footer file and html code in my post but its not hiding my content and not showing loader what should I do?

Comment: could you post a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)? It's hard to debug  such cases without the errors or code itself

Comment: this is my wp login id please sir login=admin password=password and check where is mistake I put script in footer file .CSS in css file and html in my post edit the post and select html you will see html code please check this is http://oworo.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1587&action=edit

Comment: buddy I'm not that familiar with the wordpress thing. I'm not able to find your scripts or css.